# Issues Accessing Rails Module in /lib Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autoload

I've found many similar questions on here, but none of the answers have solved my problem.

I am getting the following error upon loading my page at /user/2

```
NoMethodError in User_data#data

Showing /Users/Jimmy/Documents/Launchpad Toys/LPT_Repositories/orbit-analytics/app/views/user_data/data.erb where line #108 raised:

undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #108):

105:            </div>
106:       </div>
107:       
108:       <% if @videos_number < 1 %><p style="font-size: 18px; margin-top: 25px;">This user has no approved videos.</p>
109:       
110:       <% else %>
111:
```

This error is caused by the controller returning a null value for any and all instance variables I call in the view.

Here's the beginning of the relevant controller:

```
class UserDataController < ApplicationController

    require 'analytics_helper'

    include AnalyticsHelper

    def data

        require "date"

        @user_id = params[:user_id]
```

The error seems to be caused by the controller failing to find the module AnalyticsHelper, which is located at lib/analytics_helper.rb. Here's the beginning of the module:

```
Module AnalyticsHelper

    # Average analytics calculations for a given set of videos

    def analytics_tracker(video_ids)        
        total_likes, total_views, total_flags, total_days_visible = 0, 0, 0, 0
        total_characters, total_unique_characters, total_recurring_characters, total_custom_characters, total_custom_backgrounds = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        total_energy_level, total_emotions, total_scenes, total_duration = 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I have uncommented the line in application.rb that autoloads files in the /lib directory in Rails 3:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

I know this problem is being caused by the module failing to load but none of the solutions I've found have helped me with my problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused; what's `@videos_number`? What are those method-scoped variables and how are they related?

Comment: `@videos_number` is defined later in the controller as being the length of an ActiveRecord object and thus should never be `nil`. Removing any code in the view that could generate a null pointer exception results in the view being rendered but without any of the other instance variables called in the view returning a value, which tells me that the problem comes from the controller. The method scoped variables aren't really related to the question, I just copied the beginning 7 or so line of the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`module` shouldn't be capitalized at the beginning of your `analytics_helper.rb` file.  Try:

```
    module AnalyticsHelper
      # ...
    end
```

Comment: That did change the error message to: `NoMethodError in UserDataController#data

undefined method `analytics_tracker' for AnalyticsHelper:Module

Rails.root: /Users/Jimmy/Documents/Launchpad Toys/LPT_Repositories/orbit-analytics
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/user_data_controller.rb:120:in `data'` Line 120 in the controller is: `@user_video_analytics = AnalyticsHelper::analytics_tracker(@video_ids)` so I'm assuming the error now lies in how I'm calling that method.

Comment: Ok.  Try changing `def analytics_tracker(video_ids)` to `def self.analytics_tracker(video_ids)`.  You currently have the method defined as an instance method, but when you call it with `AnalyticsHelper::analytics_tracker(@video_ids)`, you are calling it as if it were a class method.  Adding `self` to the definition, as I suggested above, would officially change it to a class method.

Comment: Another tip to clean up the code: get rid of `require 'analytics_helper'` in your controller.  `include AnalyticsHelper` will suffice :)

Comment: That actually doesn't work, but changing the call to just `analytics_tracker(@video_ids)` did. I would prefer for it to be a class method instead of an instance method but I'm happy enough that it's working again for now. Any idea what could be making that not work? Also, thanks for the tip, I had tried including the require statement as some similar StackOverflow answers suggested that for some reason.

Comment: the same `NoMethodError` as [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640008/issues-accessing-rails-module-in-lib-directory/11640324#comment15420140_11640324)

Comment: It should work if you bring back the `AnalyticsHelper::` prefix when calling the method, _and_ add `self` to the method definition for `analytics_tracker`, at the same time.

Comment: I was doing that and it still produced that error. Your solution makes perfect sense to me too, not sure why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Try changing `include` to `extend`, and calling it with `AnalyticsHelper.analytics_tracker(@video_ids)`

Comment: I just added another method `find_by_age` to the module and am now getting a NoMethodError `undefined method 'find_by_age' for #<UserDataController:0x007fbbec83b648>` while calling that function from the same controller in the same exact way as the `analytics_tracker` function. I'm extremely confused by this.

Comment: Tried using `extend` with and without `self` in front of the methods in the module but it didn't work. I did change the method calls as well.

Comment: I'm out of ideas... It may be that the problem lies elsewhere in your code than what you have shared here.  I would read up on include/extend, and then play around with it in IRB or a separate file...first making a very simple class which includes a simple module, then slowly adding things to make it more and more similar to the real situation...that's my own personal strategy, which usually yields a lot of helpful insights.  In any case, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I've already done a couple hours worth of trial and error. Simply copying the methods into the controller makes everything work perfectly, so it seems to me that the error lies in how they're referenced and not in how the methods themselves are written. Anyways, thanks for your help.